# Querying part of a string in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to query just part of the name and get the data
Like I have data 12345678
can I somehow just search for 1234?

data.whereEqualsto("data", 1234);

This is needed because the last numbers changes and the first ones doesn't.

Comment: Not an expert here, but typically DBs allow for a variety of comparisons, like string **matching** (or string starts with, or string contains) and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to query just part of the name and get the data Like I have data 12345678 can I somehow just search for 1234?

Sure it is. When it comes to Firestore, you can simply use [.startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#startAt(double)) as seen in the following query:

```
db.collection("collName").orderBy("data").startAt(1234);
```

When it comes to the Realtime Database, you can use [.startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#startAt(java.lang.Object...)) too, but as seen below:

```
db.child("nodeName").orderByChild("data").startAt(1234);
```

But remember, both queries will return elements that are greater than `1234`. Since `12345678` is greater, it will be present in the result set.